# Redirect a URL by inserting index.php in between and truncate the url after a string in the redirect url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, truncate

I have recently ported my blog from one cms to wordpress 
so I was having trouble in redirect the tag URL which are like this

```
http://site.com/blog/tag/tagname/foobar
```

Here **"tagname"** is the name of tag created using WordPress
and **"foobar"** can be any string

I want it to redirect permanently (301) it to

```
http://site.com/blog/index.php/tagname/
```

**such that that string after the tag name i.e "foobar" is truncated and "index.php" is added in-between.**

I know there are many posts regarding .htaccess but i don't know much about its syntax except basics rules.
So i was unable to comprehend the specific solutions given on other questions to apply them to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirects from http://site.com/blog/tag/{tagname}/foobar to http.//site.com/blog/index.php/{tagname}
RewriteRule ^/blog/tag/([a-zA+])/[a-zA-Z]+$ /blog/index.php/$1/ [R=301,L]
```